# Camera live preview and barcode scanner in Ionic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

I would like to combine a camera live preview and barcode scanner functionalities in Ionic apps. 
Right now I am using the cordova barcode scanner plugin. But it doesn't allow me to keep the camera on for the next scan. I just want to close the camera when the scan was invalid, so it won't take too long to start the camera over again for the next scan.

Scandit has a plugin, whicht supports a camera live preview and scanning, but it is too expensive for my usecase.

So my idea was to use a cordova camera plugin and then add my own barcode functionality. I want to support Android and iOs. Has anyone done this before? What did you use for the barcode scanner?

Thanks.